# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

The Workplace's [third moderator election](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators is:

[image: Jane S]

She'll be joining [the existing crew](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank her for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with her as she learns the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6528209101258752/0).

Comment: Well done Jane. Like everyone else clearly thinks, I'm positive you'll do well. Everyone who voted for me: thanks. Running was really good fun, and I'm very happy with how it turned out.

Comment: https://youtu.be/xh-5FI21s6M

Comment: @JimG. OMG how awesome!  Thank you! :)))

Comment: @yochannah Thank you!  I voted for you by the way, so I firmly believe you would have been awesome! :)

Answer (score 19):

Thank you very much everyone for putting your faith in me to help moderate this fantastic community!  I am overwhelmed that so many of you voted for me, especially when there were two other very good candidates in Rory and Yochannah.

I'm currently going through the moderator toolset, just observing and trying to get a feel for everything.  There's a lot :)  I'm very aware of the additional authority that has been given to me and I'm being cautious to not accidentally overstep my bounds (hello, single-vote closing of questions!) :)

I have a very high standard to strive for set by the current moderators for this community.  I will do my very best to live up to the expectations that you have for those of us who are not here to dictate to, but to *guide* this wonderful community.  Because a community is made of people, and in particular we are here to *help* people deal with difficult situations that are impacting on their real lives.  To be able to provide some small assistance, well that in itself its own reward. :)

Comment: I told you before it was an "obvious" choice...

Comment: @aProgrammer LOL!  Well, obvious to others apparently :)

Comment: You will continue to be awesome - now you just have a few extra tools and colleagues to help out. Congratulations again. And to you too @yochannah

Comment: @RoryAlsop Thanks Rory :)  I'm trying to do some small tasks around the edges and not do too much damage :)

Answer (score 15):

Congratulations, Jane S! Thanks so much for volunteering.

And thanks to the other moderators for doing such a terrific job!

Comment: And thanks to all the candidates for stepping up!

Comment: Thanks Joe!  I'm feeling _very_ underqualified right now with experienced people such as yourself here, but I'll try to limit my number of mistakes :)

Comment: @JaneS - I've seen your recent answers to questions and I'm sure you'll be great.

Comment: Thanks again Joe :)

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations, @JANE.....congratulation again. I want to share my experience.

That was my first day in Workplace site and I Show the moderator election. I read entire information of election 2015 as well as I know there was another person who compete too. As this was the moderator election, I was read both candidate's activity and after so much thinking, finally I was given vote to you.

Its really think good that I was given vote to right candidate.

Comment: Thank you!  I am sure that both of the other candidates would have been excellent moderators too, but I am proud that so many people felt that I was capable of helping look after this community :)